# Find sumfunction? Need hints

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I have $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}x^n$, for x$\in$R. Then I have to find the sum function. I know there is many ways to find the sumfunction. But can I 
differentiate with respect to x and then find the sum of it? Then I have the differentiabel version of the sum function? Then I can take the integral from 0 to $\infty$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if convergent in the end points of the convergence interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3695999/check-if-convergent-in-the-end-points-of-the-convergence-interval)

Comment: If you're wondering what the series converges to it is $$\frac1{1-x}+\frac{\ln{(1-x)}}{x}$$

Comment: Considering the integral from  $0$ to $\infty$ of this function or of any of its derivatives is very unlikely to make much sense, because this series and all its derived series are divergent for $x\ge1$.